# how to split a DataFrame on a Boolean column

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want to split a `DataFrame`, regarding a boolean column.

I've come up with :

```
def partition(df: DataFrame, c: Column): (DataFrame, DataFrame) = 
  (df.filter(c === true), df.filter(c === false))
```

Note : in my use case, `c` is a UDF.

Is there a better way ?

I'd like :

- to avoid scanning 2 times the DataFrame
- to avoid ugly boolean tests

Here is an example :

```
@ val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(1,2,3,4)).toDF("i")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [i: int]
@ val u = udf((i: Int) => i % 2 == 0)
u: org.apache.spark.sql.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function1>, BooleanType, List(IntegerType))
@ partition(df, u($"i"))
res25: (org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) = ([i: int], [i: int])
```

Comment: can you share a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0):

use combineByKey for boolean column

```
data.combineByKey(lambda value: (value, 1),
                             lambda x, value: (x[0] + value, x[1] + 1),
                             lambda x, y: (x[0] + y[0], x[1] + y[1]))
```